# Isn't "define" a reserved keyword or macro name in C99?

Tags: c, c99

Isn't "define" a reserved keyword or macro name in C language?

```
#undef define
```

I'm surprised to find this piece of code compile just fine on GCC without any warnings or errors. Will there be any side-effects from such code?

Comment: preprocessor keywords start by `#`

Comment: no it's not. you can't do anything with just `define`,  it needs the `#`

Comment: No, `define` is not a keyword, so things like `#define define 1` and `int define = 2;` are perfectly legal, albeit confusing and therefore poor style.

Comment: @SteveSummit: There was  a time when #define define was a very bad idea but it does something reasonable now.

Comment: @Joshua Yeah, I remember, but I decided not to mention. (If we're thinking about the same thing, that was essentially an accident of one implementation; it was never a defined feature.)

Comment: Note that using `#undef define` does not mean that a subsequent `#define` will fail.  You can eve do `#define define declare` to create a macro `define` (which has no effect on how the preprocessor handles preprocessing directives).  Now, it clearly isn't sensible, but you can do the absurd if you wish.

Comment: For those curious: what @Joshua and I have been bantering about here in the comments is that back in the early days of C, with Jon Reiser's original C preprocessor, if you said `#define def define`, it substituted `def` *everywhere*, even in later `#` lines, so you could say `#def FALSE 0` and it would be just like you had said `#define FALSE 0`.  But, like so many other preprocessor quirks, this never saw much use outside of the IOCCC.  (And if you redefined `define` itself, the results would have been... interesting.)

Comment: @SteveSummit not very interesting: `printf '%s\n' '#define define define' '#define foo bar' | apout $APOUT_ROOT/lib/cpp` => `2: define: macro recursion`, `2: undefined control` (`APOUT_ROOT` is the unpacked [v7.tar.gz](https://www.tuhs.org/Archive/Distributions/Research/Henry_Spencer_v7/v7.tar.gz)).

Answer (score 4):

`define` is not a keyword in C, `#define` is (it's really two tokens so `# define` also works; but define not preceded by a # is not reserved).

Nevertheless, you can redefine keywords all you want in C. That is only disallowed in C++, and most compilers have an option for reversing this (bad*) decision.

I just tested compiling this code:

```
#define auto
int main(){}
```

`auto` is a keyword in C and this builds just fine.

If you can define something, you can undefine it with `#undef`. `#undef` doesn't check if something is a macro first, and this is intentional. Using `#undef` on a non-macro is a noop.

My older manuals referred to using `#undef` on `fgetc` and `fputc` if you wanted to take their address. Obviously this wouldn't be portable unless it were safe to `#undef fgetc` even when it wasn't a macro.

<sup>*Linux kernel header: `struct namespace {`; if you can't do `#define namespace namespace_` you can't fix it for C++.</sup>

Comment: Nitpick: `#define` is two (preprocessing) tokens, `#` and `define` (and yes, you are perfectly allowed to put horizontal whitespace in between), so it is inaccurate to say that `#define` is a keyword.  What really happens is, whenever the first pp-token on a line is `#`, the second pp-token is examined to see if it is the name of a preprocessing directive, _without_ macro-expanding it first.

Comment: You don't have blanket license to `#define` keywords in C.  C11 [§7.1.2 Standard headers ¶4](https://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.2p4) says: _The program shall not have any macros with names lexically identical to keywords currently defined prior to the inclusion of the header or when any macro defined in the header is expanded._

Comment: The use of `#undef` on C standard library routines/macros is supported by C 2018 7.1.4 1, so it is portable. You do not need it to take the address of a function, though, since the lack of parentheses in `&foo` means a function-like macro will not be invoked.

Comment: Or you could use `(fgetc)` and `(fputc)` to bypass any function-like macros with those names.

Comment: @JonatganLeffler: port70 cert revoked. Got another link? You're not wrong though.

Comment: @Joshua here, I deleted the **`s`** in `https://` for you: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.2p4

Answer (score 1):

`define` is not a C keyword, but part of a *preprocessing directive*, which includes the *whole line*, starting with `#` (optionally preceded by whitespace). Preprocessing directives have their own syntax and "keywords", different from those of the C language, and which you cannot override via macros.

To understand the difference, try this with `cc -E`:

```c
#define ifndef  ifdef
#define one 1

#ifndef one
wtf?
#else
"ifndef" not recognized as a macro
#endif

#ifdef ifndef
"ifndef" recognized as a macro
#else
wtf?
#endif
```

Comment: Compiled fine with -E option.